# How come returned inner functions reference the same outer function variable even when the outer function is fired multiple times?

Tags: javascript, function, debouncing

I am trying to understand how this debounce function works:

```
const myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");

myInput.addEventListener(
    "keyup",
    debounce( helloWorld, 2000 )
);

function debounce( callback, delay ) {
    let timeout;
    return function() {
        clearTimeout( timeout );
        timeout = setTimeout( callback, delay );
    }
}
```

From my understanding, every time someone performs a "keyup" action, a new debounce function is fired and added to the call stack. Now it is my belief that each one of these debounce functions has its own independent notion of "timeout" which the inner function acts on. However, the actual case it seems is that when "keyup" is performed many times, multiple inner functions are returned that all seem to share a reference to the same "timeout" variable, which allows this function to work.

My question is, where does my understanding fall apart? When "keyup" is fired multiple times, is it true that there are multiple debounce functions going to the call stack? Or is it just one function with one timeout variable, but with multiple returned functions?

Comment: No, `debounce` is *executed* when `addEventListener` is *executed*, not when the event fires. When the event fires, it is the argument that is passed to `addEventListener` that is called, i.e. the function returned by that single execution of `debounce`.

Comment: Your code produces the same behavior as this one: https://jsfiddle.net/cfun2wo9/ I suspect the main hangup here is to keep in mind that the second argument of an `addEventListener()` call is supposed to be a *function*. `debounce(helloWorld, 2000)` however is a function *call*, so whatever is *returned* by that call is what is passed to addEventListener. The called function returns a secondary function though, which is what makes this work.

Answer (score 0):

The `debounce` is called once. Then each time you release the key inner function is called.

You can check this by adding a `console.log` inside the `debounce`

The second argument that is passed to `addEventListener` is the inne function of the `debounce`

Inner function is also created only once when you initialize the listener. This function is just called every time listener fires.